# Fantaxtic plot - how do I change the order of my chronological and numerical data?

Tags: r, phyloseq

I am creating graphs with Fantaxtic for phyloseq. I am creating graphs from the same data in two ways.

Grouping samples by month: I need to display the months in chronological order, not alphabetical. I tried to set the orders of the months as such but it still is in alphabetical order in the plot.

```
sample_data(ps)$Month = factor(sample_data(ps)$Month, 
                                         levels = c("Nov 2020","Apr 2021","May 2021","Jul 2021", "Feb 2022", "Mar 2022", "Apr 2022"))

ps_norm <- transform_sample_counts(ps, function(x) x / sum(x) )
top_order <- top_taxa(ps_norm, n_taxa = 15, tax_level = "Order")

plot_nested_bar(top_order$ps_obj,
                top_level = "Phylum",
                nested_level = "Order") +
  facet_wrap(~Month_2,
             scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Grouping by location: I need to display sample names in numerical order. R is interpreting 900 as larger than 1000 due to the first digit.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with `phyloseq`, but it seems suspect to me that the data you change the levels of is `sample_data(ps)$Month`, and then you transform it and extract top counts before plotting `top_order`. Can you inspect the `Month` column of `top_order` and verify it has levels in the correct order, and if not correct it there?

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of fantaxtic. Unfortunately, information about order of the levels in the data is lost when `psmelt` is called. However, you can easily change the order of your facets in your call to `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`; [see this example](https://www.statology.org/ggplot-facet-order/). I hope that resolves your issue.

In the future, feel free to submit these questions/issues directly to the [fantaxtic repository on github](https://github.com/gmteunisse/Fantaxtic) so that I can quickly resolve your issues.